# Matriz Loop com vários vetores: Pyhton

Tags: python, matriz

Boa noite pessoal

**Sou iniciante no Python** e gostaria da ajuda de vocês, fiz esse programa mas as resposta esta em forma de vários vetores ou seja 24 vetores, sendo que na realidade eu queria apenas uma matrix(24,1), segue abaixo o que fiz, desde já agradeço:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

ex = pd.read_excel('3.1.xlsx')
meanX1 = np.mean(ex.X1)
meanX2 = np.mean(ex.X2)
meanI = np.mean(ex.I)
stdX1 =np.std(ex.X1)
stdX2 =np.std(ex.X2)
stdI =np.std(ex.I)

for i in range(0, 25):
        aux = np.zeros([1,1])
        X1std = aux + (ex.X1[i] - meanX1)/stdX1
        print(X1std)
```

a resposta é essa com 24 vetores, gostaria de um matrix coluna com 24 linhas:

```
[[-0.26102763]]
[[-0.85427226]]
[[-0.85427226]]
[[-0.7059611]]
[[-0.40933879]]
[[-0.26102763]]
[[-1.00258342]]
[[-0.26102763]]
[[3.15012896]]
[[-0.55764995]]
[[1.07377277]]
[[0.18390583]]
[[-0.7059611]]
[[-0.40933879]]
[[0.03559468]]
[[0.18390583]]
[[-0.40933879]]
[[-0.26102763]]
[[-0.85427226]]
[[1.22208393]]
[[0.18390583]]
[[2.55688433]]
[[0.03559468]]
[[-0.11271648]]
[[-0.7059611]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É bem tranquilo de fazer, só precisa inicializar uma matriz de zeros do tamanho que você deseja e depois ir preenchendo com os valores que você obtém.

```
import numpy as np

Matriz = np.zeros((24,1)) # Inicializa a matriz no formato de 24 linhas por 1 coluna,                               com zeros

for item in range(24):
    Matriz[item][0] = item  # Preenche a matriz com o índice do for

print(Matriz)

print(Matriz[2][0]) # Imprime o valor da 3ª linha
```

Não consigui rodar o seu código devido a dependências de outros lugares, mas o código que fiz gera a saída:

```
[[ 0.]
 [ 1.]
 [ 2.]
 [ 3.]
 [ 4.]
 [ 5.]
 [ 6.]
 [ 7.]
 [ 8.]
 [ 9.]
 [10.]
 [11.]
 [12.]
 [13.]
 [14.]
 [15.]
 [16.]
 [17.]
 [18.]
 [19.]
 [20.]
 [21.]
 [22.]
 [23.]]
2.0
```

Comment: Muito obrigado !!! sua ideia me levou para outros caminhos e tentei a sua também sem sucesso, fui encontrar a resposta no Pandas da seguinte forma:XIstd = pd.Series([(ex.XI[i] - meanXI)/stdXI for i in range(0, 25)])
XI = XIstd.values

Comment: Por nada, considere avaliar a resposta.